# Referencing Library in ASP.NET Core 1.0 (vNext)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, asp.net-core, coreclr

I am learning ASP.NET Core 1.0 (vNext). With that in mind, I have a solution that is structured like this:

```
MySolution
  src
    MyLibrary
      MyClass.cs
      project.json
    MyWebSite
      Startup.cs
      project.json
```

I am successfully compiling `MyLibrary` from the command-line using `dnu build`. I ran `dnu pack` which generated `MyLibrary.1.0.0.nupkg`. There are also two folders: `dnx451` and `dnxcore50` which both contain `MyLibrary.1.0.0.dll`. I want to use `MyLibrary` in `MyWebSite`, however, I'm confused.

1. How do I "include" `MyLibrary` into `MyWebSite`? Do I manually copy over the `.dll` file? If so, which one? Should I use the `nupkg` file instead? This is a private assembly, I do not want to publish it globally via NuGet.
2. What do I put in `MyWebSite/project.json` to reference the `MyLibrary` assembly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to publish the package to NuGet if you don't want to share it with other people/projects outside of your solution. You can just reference the package directly from source.

However, if that still doesn't work for you then you have three options:

1. Internalize using Roslyn. Example: [project.json](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager/project.json#L20) and the [actual code](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/ext/compiler/preprocess/Internalization.cs)
2. You can reference the sources directly. Example [project.json](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager/project.json#L17)
3. Create a build time dependency. Example [project.json](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager/project.json#L5-L6) and [actual code for the package](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.CommandLineUtils.Sources)

Answer (score 6):

Are you using Visual Studio 2015 RC? If so then follow these steps:

1. Expand your web project in the Solution Explorer
2. Right click on **References**
3. Click on **Add Reference...** from the context menu
4. Select **Projects** from the **Reference Manager**
5. Tick the checkbox next to **MyLibrary**
6. Click **OK**
7. Profit

If you are not using visual studio then this can be achieved by updated the project.json file in your web project.

If you created a "vNext class library project" then add this to the **dependencies** property on the json object:

```
"dependencies": {
      "MyLibrary": "1.0.0-*"
   }
```

Comment: I am using vNext. However, where does the runtime look for a library referenced in the dependencies of the project.json file? The .dll file needs to be somewhere so that the application can use it. I'm not sure where it belongs though.

Answer (score 3):

1. Several questions marked in bold.

(**How do I "include" MyLibrary into MyWebSite?**)
In MyWebSite/project.json: Add the reference like this (don't worry about the version number not showing up).
[image: Add VS2015RC class library reference]

**(Do I manually copy over the .dll file?)**

No

**(This is a private assembly, I do not want to publish it globally via NuGet.)**

Then don't do that :)

Referencing your class library from your web application will make sure it is included when building the web application. Then you should copy your web application files to an application server able to run it. I think you should try to publish your web application to an Azure Web app and then use server explorer to look at what the files on the server looks like after publishing. Or did you already know there is no reason to make a package before using it in you web app?