# Asp.Net Core - simplest possible forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, forms-authentication

I have this old MVC5 application that uses forms authentication in the simplest possible form. There is only one account stored in web.config, there are no roles etc.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Index" timeout="30">
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
      <user name="some-user" password="some-password" />
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

The login routine just calls

```
FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(name, password);
```

And that's it.
Is there something similar (in terms of simplicity) in asp.net core?

Comment: Authentication with FormAuth is not compatible with asp.net core. Rather use Identity

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It is not that simple :)

1. In the Startup.cs, configure method.

   ```
   app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
   {
     options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
     options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
     options.LoginPath = "/Home/Login";
   });
   ```
2. Add Authorize attribute to protect the resources you want to secure.

   ```
   [Authorize]
   public IActionResult Index()
   {
     return View();
   }
   ```
3. In the Home Controller, Login Post action method, write the following method.

   ```
   var username = Configuration["username"];
   var password = Configuration["password"];
   if (authUser.Username == username && authUser.Password == password)
   {
     var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, 
         CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

     HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(
       CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
       new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));

     return Redirect("~/Home/Index");
   }
   else
   {
     ModelState.AddModelError("","Login failed. Please check Username and/or password");
   }
   ```

Here is the github repo for your reference : https://github.com/anuraj/CookieAuthMVCSample

Comment: I use your code but it gives an error `cannot convert lambda expression to type` in Startup.cs, configure method.

Comment: @SanyamiVaidya which version of asp.net core you're using?

Comment: I'm using 1.0.1 version of asp.net core

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44277688/cannot-convert-lambda-expression-to-type-cookieauthenticationoptions-because-i

Comment: Could you clarify what the value of variable `claims` is? It is not expressed in the scope of the step 3. snippet.

Comment: It is something like this - var claims = new[] { new Claim("name", authUser.Username), new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin") };

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: The UseCookieAuthentication extension method is obsolete now. That's why modern NuGet leaves you with compilation error for it. Refer to @MattLengenfelder 's link

Answer (score 36):

To add to Anuraj's answer - a number of classes have been deprecated for .Net Core 2. FYI:

Startup.cs - In ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(o => o.LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login"));
```

Startup.cs - In Configure:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

In your account/login controller method/wherever you're doing your authentication:

```
var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "MyUserNameOrID"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "SomeRoleName") };

var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

await context.SignInAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
    new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
// Do your redirect here
```

Sources:
https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/232

https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1310

Comment: Was having issues with looping back to login form doing dual auth with jwt and cookies. Turns out changing from await context.SignInAsync(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity)); to await context.SignInAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
    new ClaimsPrincipal(identity)); did the trick. Thanks @AndyP9!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 0):

A little update for MVC ASP.NET Core 6 for Anuraj's answer...
(The .net core 5 answer no longer works in .net core 6)

1. In the Program.cs, configure method.

   // Forms Authentication
   builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddCookie(o => o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Login"));

   ...

   // Forms Authentication

   app.UseAuthentication();
2. Add Authorize attribute to protect the resources you want to secure.

   [Authorize]
   public IActionResult Index()
   {
   return View();
   }
3. In the Home Controller, Login Post action method, write the
   following method.

   var username = Configuration["username"];

   var password = Configuration["password"];

   if (authUser.Username == username && authUser.Password == password)
   {

   var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username) };

   var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims,
   CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

   HttpContext.SignInAsync(
   CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
   new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));

   return Redirect("~/Home/Index");
   }

   else

   {

   ModelState.AddModelError("","Login failed. Please check Username and/or password");

   }