# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'CookieAuthenticationOptions' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, forms-authentication

I'm using `1.0.1` version of `asp.net core` and I'm using authentication in my form.

I use `UseCookieAuthentication` and its gives an error

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'CookieAuthenticationOptions' because 
>   it is not a delegate type

In the `Startup.cs`, configure method.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

    app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSession();

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
        options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
        options.LoginPath = "/Home/Login";
    });

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=About}/{id?}"
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you want to do and what the problem is in more detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass in the options, not a lambda:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    LoginPath = "/Home/Login"
});
```

Comment: Oops, forgot to change semicolons to commas :D