# ASP.NET MVC Core Visual Studios Mac: Type or Namespace Could not be found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I just started an asp.net mvc core project and for some reason when I try to use HttpCookieCollection in my controller method like below, I get "Type or Namespace Could not be found". I have imported System.Web also. What could be the issue?

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    HttpCookieCollection cookies = Request.Cookies;
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Is this method inside your controller??

Comment: @GaganDeep Yes it is.

Comment: What kind of a project is this??

Comment: @GaganDeep asp.net mvc core

Comment: I haven't worked with core. but could you try this.    string cookieValueFromContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["key"];

Comment: see if this gives you the value of a cookie.

Comment: In ASP.NET Core, `Request.Cookies` is of type `IRequestCookieCollection`, not `HttpCookieCollection`. Also, *please*, [no `System.Web`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912473/can-system-web-be-used-with-asp-net-core-with-full-framework)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the asp.net core `Request.Cookies` type is  `IRequestCookieCollection` and it's part of `Microsoft.AspnetCore.Http` namespace!

So you must change your code to:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IRequestCookieCollection cookies = Request.Cookies;
    var cookie = cookies["cookieKey"];
    return View();
}
```