# How do I use System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting in .NET Core apps?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, data-visualization

I've used the System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting namespace a lot in ASP.NET MVC 5, Windows Forms, WPF and UWP apps but cannot see how you can use this namespace in .NET Core Web Apps?

I'm targeting .NET Core 2.1

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you end up proceeding? We're migrating our .NET Framework class libraries (which used System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting extensively) to .NET Core / Standard so are interested in alternatives...

Comment: @justin I think I gave up in the end

Comment: @Justin were you able to find any solution? Your input is much appreciated.

Comment: @PavithranR For the long term, we started writing our charts in Angular with the Fusion Charts package, which is quite robust. For the short term where we still need the legacy System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting charts, we maintain an old .NET Framework ASP.NET app that can leverage this package, but accesses its data through JSON api calls from our web api (which is now .NET 7) rather than getting data directly through class libraries (which would have hamstrung our class libraries on using .NET Standard.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `System.Web` namespace is not available on .Net Core, the reason being, it is tied to Windows through dependencies on things like `http.sys`.

While it may be possible to use it running Asp.Net Core on top of the full framework, you will find you loose a lot of the benefits of using core in the first place. I've not tried this namespace personally, but going off of other [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40927239/1506635), it probably won't work properly anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I feared as much. I suppose I could try and use another charting library (there are a lot of them). I just love the DataVisualization so much!