# Reference to type '' claims it is defined in 'System.Web', but it could not be found

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget-package

I'm working on a .NET Core 2 application, I have a Nuget package that I need that is only written in Framework 4.6. I've downloaded the Nuget package and initially there are no problems with creating an Instance of the class.

However when I try to use one of the methods I get an error in VS 2017 saying "Reference to type '' claims it is defined in 'System.Web', but it could not be found" , "Module 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' should be referenced".

I've read several posts saying that it may not be possible to reference System.Web.dll which is needed.

However I've also seen these:

[Using external .dll in dot net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108106/using-external-dll-in-dot-net-core?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[.net core 1.0 visual studio referencing external dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183649/net-core-1-0-visual-studio-referencing-external-dll)

I've tried adding it as a reference to the project as well as using [Nuget Package Explorer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/nuget-package-explorer/9wzdncrdmdm3?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab) to create a Nuget package with System.Web in it.

Can I solve this issue by correctly referencing the System.Web.dll or is this not possible in .NET Core 2?

Comment: What package are you trying to install? You won't be able to use classic ASP.NET stuff in .NET Core

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It's a custom package from work that was written in .Net Framework

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to use APIs of the `System.Web` namespace / dlls in .NET Core 2.

While it is possible to use .NET Framework NuGet packages and DLLs, this compatibility layer is only a best-effort approach and may fail if the external code tries to use APIs that are not available in .NET Core, such as types in `System.Web`.

Comment: Then what should we use as an alternative?